# Add query executed user information to Mysql binlog

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, binlog, mysqlbinlog

We are using MYSQL as our production database and we have setup another salve for read requests. Time to time various database users can execute insert/update queries on master database. If we want identify those executed queries (auditing/troubleshooting) we are using mysql bingos for it (reading after decoding it). From mysql binlog we can identify the query but we cant identify the executed user. is their a way to get that query executed user info into binlog. Enable general log  wont be a option due to performance issues.

Comment: Adding information to the binlog requires modifying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about general log, but this behavior belongs to auditing system.  If you don't insist to write into binlog, both Oracle and Percona offer solutions:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/audit-log.html
- https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/management/audit_log_plugin.html

Comment: I agree, I use the Percona audit_log plugin with my MySQL databases, and it works really well. Gives you everything you want, and then some.